# Draggable item is moving behind other components on the screen

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a isand builder application and I want the user to be able to drag an item to the map. The map is implemented using lazyRows and Lazy Columns to act like a 2d grid. The structures are located under the map in a LazyRow. I want the user to be able to drag the item onto the map. When dragging onto the map the item goes behind the map.

This is the draggable item

```java
@Composable
private fun DraggableStructure(img: Int, name: String) {
var offsetX by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
var offsetY by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
var startOffsetX by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
var startOffsetY by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
var isDragging by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = {
                            startOffsetX = offsetX
                            startOffsetY = offsetY
                            isDragging = true
                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            offsetX = startOffsetX
                            offsetY = startOffsetY
                            isDragging = false
                        },
                        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()
                            offsetX += dragAmount.x
                            offsetY += dragAmount.y
                        }
                    )
                }
        ) {
            val imageSize = min(maxHeight, maxWidth) * 0.75f
            Column {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = img),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(imageSize)
                        .height(imageSize)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                )
                Text(
                    text = name,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is where the draggable items are stored

```java
@Composable``your text``
    private fun ItemSelection() {
        val structureImages = mapOf(
            "Building 1" to R.drawable.ic_building1,
            "Building 2" to R.drawable.ic_building2
            // These is more here
        )
        LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp)) {
            item {
                val mapData by remember { mutableStateOf(MapData.get()) }
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        mapData.value?.regenerate()
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
                {
                    Text(text = "Regenerate Map")
                }
            }
            items(structureImages.size) { index ->
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp))
                DraggableStructure(
                    img = structureImages.values.elementAt(index),
                    name = structureImages.keys.elementAt(index)
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the map

```java
@Composable
    private fun GameMap() {
        val mapData by remember { mutableStateOf(MapData.get()) }
        LazyRow(state = rememberLazyListState()) {
            items(MapData.WIDTH) { colIndex ->
                BoxWithConstraints {
                    // The size of each cell is the minimum of the maxWidth and maxHeight divided by the number of cells.
                    // And then divided by a value to make the cells a bit smaller for the structures row
                    val cellSize = min(maxWidth, maxHeight) / (MapData.HEIGHT * 1.25f)
                    LazyColumn(state = rememberLazyListState()) {
                        items(MapData.HEIGHT) { rowIndex ->
                            val mapElement = mapData.value?.get(rowIndex, colIndex)
                            Box(modifier = Modifier.size(cellSize)) {
                                if (mapElement != null) {
                                    Image(
                                        painter = painterResource(id = mapElement.northWest),
                                        contentDescription = null,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                                            .size((cellSize.value * 0.51).dp)
                                    )
                                    Image(
                                        painter = painterResource(id = mapElement.northEast),
                                        contentDescription = null,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                                            .size((cellSize.value * 0.51).dp)
                                    )
                                    Image(
                                        painter = painterResource(id = mapElement.southWest),
                                        contentDescription = null,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                                            .size((cellSize.value * 0.51).dp)
                                    )
                                    Image(
                                        painter = painterResource(id = mapElement.southEast),
                                        contentDescription = null,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                                            .size((cellSize.value * 0.51).dp)
                                    )
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how they are strucrued in the main activity

```java
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                MainLayout()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun MainLayout() {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            GameMap()
            ItemSelection()
        }
    }
```

I was expected the dragable item to be able to moved across the map but instead it goes behind it. I tried to change the z-index for the item to a very high value but it did not work. I could not find a way to move dragable items outside of their parent composable. I've been stuck on this for a while now and would really apprecicate the help thanks
[gif of what happens](https://gifyu.com/image/S4V4e)

Answer (score -1):

In your current implementation, the issue is that the draggable items are being rendered within the same Box as the game map, which means they will always be drawn underneath the game map. To achieve the desired behavior where the draggable items can be moved across the map, you should place them outside of the Box containing the game map and handle their position separately.

Here's an updated implementation:

Create a container Box for the draggable items at the top of your MainLayout:

```
@Composable
private fun MainLayout() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        // Container for draggable items
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp) // Adjust the height as needed
        ) {
            ItemSelection()
        }
        GameMap()
    }
}
```

Modify your ItemSelection composable to use a LazyRow with draggable items:

```
@Composable
private fun ItemSelection() {
    val structureImages = mapOf(
        "Building 1" to R.drawable.ic_building1,
        "Building 2" to R.drawable.ic_building2
        // Add more items here
    )

    LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp)) {
        items(structureImages.size) { index ->
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp))
            DraggableStructure(
                img = structureImages.values.elementAt(index),
                name = structureImages.keys.elementAt(index)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

With these changes, the draggable items will be rendered in a separate container at the top of the screen and will not be obscured by the game map. You can then handle their position independently of the game map by using the offsetX and offsetY state variables within the DraggableStructure composable.

Make sure to adjust the height and styling of the container for draggable items (Box in MainLayout) to fit your design requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't seem to fix anything, It's still the same issue as before, but now the items are placed above the map.

Comment: Is this answer AI-generated? If so, you should delete it, because such content is banned on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking as well, it had the chat-gtp accent